# MFC ON_WM_TIMER() issue with static cast

Tags: c++, mfc

Having problems with ON_WM_TIMER in my class CDatabaseApplicationApp which extends CWinApp

```
> 1>c:\programs\databaseapplication\databaseapplication\databaseapplication.cpp(20):
> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall
> CDatabaseApplicationApp::* )(UINT_PTR)' to 'void (__thiscall CWnd::*
> )(UINT_PTR)' 1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion
> requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I've included the function `OnTimer`:

```
class CLifescanDatabaseApplicationApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CLifescanDatabaseApplicationApp();
protected:
    CLifescanDatabaseApplicationDlg * m_ptheWindow;
// Overrides
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR nTimerID);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

`OnTimer` is just:

```
void CDatabaseApplicationApp::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nTimerID)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Help"));
}
```

The timer is set using an define at the top of the source file:

```
#define ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY 1
```

and `SetTimer` is defined in

```
BOOL CDatabaseApplicationApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();


    AfxEnableControlContainer();
AfxInitRichEdit2();
    // Create the shell manager, in case the dialog contains
    // any shell tree view or shell list view controls.
    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));



    m_ptheWindow = new CDatabaseApplicationDlg();
    m_pMainWnd = m_ptheWindow;
    if(m_ptheWindow!=nullptr)
    {
        m_ptheWindow->Create(CDatabaseApplicationDlg::IDD,CWnd::GetDesktopWindow());
        m_ptheWindow->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
    // Delete the shell manager created above.
    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    if(!m_ptheWindow->SetTimer(ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY,10000,nullptr))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return TRUE;
}
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: is this the real code? You don't use `OnTimer` in SetTimer, neither there is a `static_cast` anywhere

Comment: Yes, it's real code. Not sure what you mean by OnTimer in SetTimer, examples in the Prosise book and on internet have both.

Comment: compiler complains about `static_cast` in line 20 of databaseapplication.cpp. This is not shown in the code you submitted. Since you didn't specify the callback in `SetTimer` it will call `OnTimer` method in the class on which you call `SetTimer` which is `CDatabaseApplicationDlg`, so you need to override `OnTimer` there.

Comment: So how would I call SetTimer on a class without a window. You'll have to explain a Callback, as I've not used one before, sorry.

Comment: I have added the answer. However, I am still unclear about where did the `static_cast` come from.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `SetTimer` for the main window,

```
if(!m_ptheWindow->SetTimer(ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY,10000,nullptr))
 {
     return false;
 }
```

the `OnTimer` override should probably be in the window class (deriving from `CWnd`), not in the application class.

Comment: The application is just a modeless dialog box providing options to query a database, but I don't want to do my processing there. I needed to put the m_PtheWindow-> part in or it wanted a SetTimer with four arguments, which didn't make sense.

Comment: The "four argument version" is the Win32 API, outside of MFC. The error message says that it expects a `CWnd` member function, which you can get from the window class. Possibly, you can have the window's `onTimer` function pass the message on to the app class. MFC itself doesn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`CWnd::SetTimer` takes as the last argument a pointer to a function which will be called to process WM_TIMER message (a callback function).

If this argument is set to NULL, `OnTimer` method of that window will be called, which means you have to override the `OnTimer` method of your `CDatabaseApplicationDlg` class.

If you don't want to do that, you need to explicitly specify the callback function, i.e. some other function which will be called to process the message. This can be a global function or a static class member. However, non-static class member will not work out of the box as member function pointers are not really pointers so you need to wrap them into something else.

If your `CDatabaseApplication` class would have a **static** member like:

```
void CDatabaseApplicationApp::OnTimer(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
   // in your case:
   // hWnd => HWND of your ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY instance
   // nMsg => WM_TIMER
   // nIDEvent => ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY, unless you also set other timers
   // dwTime => elapsed time, same as value of GetTickCount()
   AfxMessageBox(_T("Help"));
}
```

then you could setup the timer like this:

```
m_ptheWindow->SetTimer(ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY, 10000, CDatabaseApplicationApp::OnTimer)
```

Comment: This doesn't work; error C2664: 'CWnd::SetTimer' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (__cdecl *)(UINT_PTR)' to 'void (__stdcall *)(HWND,UINT,UINT_PTR,DWORD)'
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick :) SetTimer takes a callback compatible with Win API signature, not MFC one. I have updated the example

Comment: Ok, solved by removing all ON_WM_TIMER(), and changing the static function to  static void CALLBACK OnTimer(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime); and the SetTimer to  if(!::SetTimer(NULL,ID_TIMER_DATABASEQUERY,10000, CLifescanDatabaseApplicationApp::OnTimer))      Not very impressed that you have to go a very complicated route to get something simple to work.

Comment: Actually, it is very simple - you just need to override `CWnd's OnTimer`. How do you expect application to know which OnTimer method in all unrelated classes to call?

Answer (score 0):

[Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/timers) are conceptually simple:

You call [`SetTimer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) with an ID, a time-out value, and a recipient, and the system delivers [`WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) messages to the recipient whenever the time-out elapses until the subscription is canceled with a call to [`KillTimer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-killtimer).

The time-out value (`uElapse`) is easily understood: It is an unsigned 32-bit value that describes the timer's recurrence interval (in milliseconds), clamped to the inclusive range `[USER_TIMER_MINIMUM .. USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM]`.

Sadly, this is where simplicity ends.

---

"Recipient" and "(effective) timer ID" form an interwoven network of interrelated input and return values, with semantics for the supplied ID depending on the values passed through the two remaining parameters, `hWnd` and `lpTimerFunc`. Things are further complicated since `SetTimer()` can either install a new timer or replace an existing timer.

That's a fair bit to detangle.

#### Recipient

The designated recipient is communicated by way of the `hWnd` and `lpTimerFunc` arguments and can be either

- a window (`hWnd` is non-NULL), or
- a user-provided callback function (`lpTimerFunc` is non-NULL)

If it is a window, a `WM_TIMER` message is delivered to the [window procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-procedures) associated with that window. If it is a callback, the system calls the user-supplied callback instead. Delegation is handled internally by the [`DispatchMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage) implementation, which MFC calls on our behalf already.

The remaining combinations of `hWnd` and `lpTimerFunc` (where both are NULL or non-NULL) aren't called out in the documentation. The behavior is unspecified, and the rule thus becomes that *exactly* one of `hWnd` and `lpTimerFunc` must be non-NULL.

To make the remainder easier to explain, we'll call a timer where `hWnd` is non-NULL a *"window timer,"* and a timer where `lpTimerFunc` is non-NULL a *"callback timer."* Those aren't official terms.

#### Timer ID

The timer ID (`nIDEvent`) identifies the timer and can be used in the window procedure or callback to disambiguate between several active timers.

The ID needs to be unique.

When installing a "window timer," the window class implementation is responsible for inventing a value that nobody else is using<sup>1</sup>. For a "callback timer," the system manages ID assignments. The caller still needs to supply an ID value that isn't currently assigned. 0 is an invalid ID for a "callback timer," so that makes for a good choice.

For either timer, `SetTimer()` returns 0 if it fails to create a timer. For a "callback timer" only, a non-zero return value represents the system-assigned timer ID.

The above applies to timer creation, but `SetTimer()` can also replace an existing timer. Thankfully, the rules are much more consistent in that case: When the combination of `hWnd` and `nIDEvent` identifies an existing timer, the timer is replaced. A non-zero return value reports success. Otherwise, the operation failed.

#### MFC

With the fundamental API details covered, it should be much easier to understand how this translates to MFC. The [`ON_WM_TIMER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-messages-t-z) message map entry can be used for "window timers" only. It expands to

```cpp
#define ON_WM_TIMER() \
    { WM_TIMER, 0, 0, 0, AfxSig_v_up_v, \
        (AFX_PMSG)(AFX_PMSGW) \
        (static_cast< void (AFX_MSG_CALL CWnd::*)(UINT_PTR) > ( &ThisClass :: OnTimer)) },
```

The crucial part is the `static_cast` that tries to convert the `OnTimer()` member function pointer to a member function pointer of the `CWnd` class. The cast fails if `ThisClass` doesn't derive from `CWnd`. That explains the compiler error you are seeing.

If you need a timer in a class that doesn't derive from `CWnd`, you have to use a "callback timer" instead, with the following ingredients: A [callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-timerproc) (a free function or a `static` class member), and a place to track the system-assigned timer ID.

```cpp
class CDatabaseApplicationApp : public CWinApp
{
    // ...
    static void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD) noexcept;
    static UINT_PTR s_TimerId;
};
```

```cpp
static UINT_PTR CDatabaseApplicationApp::s_TimerId = 0;

static void CALLBACK CDatabaseApplicationApp::TimerProc(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR id, DWORD) noexcept {
    if (id == s_TimerId) {
        // Handle timer event
    } else {
        // Ignore other timers
    }
}

BOOL CDatabaseApplicationApp::InitInstance() {
    // ...
    s_TimerId = ::SetTimer(nullptr, 0, 10000, &CDatabaseApplicationApp::TimerProc);
    if (s_TimerId == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}

CDatabaseApplicationApp::~CDatabaseApplicationApp() {
    if (s_TimerId != 0) {
        ::KillTimer(nullptr, s_TimerId);
        s_TimerId = 0;
    }
}
```

With that in place, the system calls into `TimerProc()` whenever the time-out expires. One last wrinkle: With `TimerProc()` a `static` class member, it no longer has access to `CDatabaseApplicationApp`'s instance data. If that is needed, a call to [`AfxGetApp()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management#afxgetapp) returns a pointer to the `CWinApp` base class that can be cast as appropriate.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[A window can’t have two timers with the same ID, so how do I assign an ID that nobody else is using?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191009-00/?p=102974) explains how to do that.*